# Ajax & PHP - how to trigger window.open right after data is insert to popup new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My problem is the new window or page pops up everytime and non stop - it was like a loop.

what my page does is when I insert data then it automatically send to the page and that is working well i have the ajax code that automatically send the data without REFRESH. now when I add this `window.open` the page automatically loads new pages.

What my expected output is, When I insert data that is the ONLY time that the new page will load or popup. here is my pages, codes and javascript code

`content.php` this is where I fetch the data that is sended to the database

`<div id=getdata></div>`

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dis()
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "select.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    window.open("http://localhost/ppa/movies.php", "", "width=1500px,height=1000px");  


  }

  dis();

  setInterval(function(){
  dis();
  },2000);
</script>
```

`select.php` this is where the `xmlhttp.open` get url. and this is where I manage to bring my data so it will fetched to the `content.php`

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","423");
    mysqli_select_db($link, "wasapp");

    $res = mysqli_query($link,"select * from announcement");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
?>




  <div class="overlay">
      <br><br><br><br><br>
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-12">
             <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: rgba(42, 44, 45, 0.9); color: #71777f">
              <h3><?php echo $row['additional_info']; ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  


  </div>

<?php } ?>
```

`announcement.php`

this is where I insert the data so that it will send to the database..

```
    $stmt1 = $pdo->prepare("insert announcement set additional_info=:addInfo");
```

nothing special about this code, more on  just query and inserts

Comment: you need to open after ajax success.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra can you please help me sir? im not that familiar with ajax. im just learning php for a while. thanks, I just made this thanks to a video

Comment: You are getting popup again n again cause you are calling dis function in every 2 seconds by this code:  setInterval(function(){
  dis();
  },2000);. I think you should only call dis function when you insert any data. Currently calling ajax every 2 seconds will increase load on your server. Avoid that.

Comment: @RohitMittal , can you please let me help with the code? thank

Comment: why you need to open a page every 2 seconds? or if that's not intended state when you need to open new page? for me to help you out

Answer (score 1):

You can make a global variable where you can assign database records count. On every ajax call, you should get total record count from php file. You can cross check these variables. If global variable and ajax response variable is same, then you should not popup the window else your should. Have a look of below code:

```
<script>
        var recordCount = 0; 
        function dis()
        {
            var responseRecordCount = 0;
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                responseRecordCount = this.responseText.sqlRecordCount; // sqlRecordCount is dummy variable. You should pass count of database records here
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "select.php",false);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            if (recordCount != responseRecordCount) {
                document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                window.open("http://localhost/ppa/movies.php", "", "width=1500px,height=1000px");                          
            }
        }

        dis();

        setInterval(function(){
        dis();
        },2000);
    </script>
```

Hope it helps you to make this approach for betterment your code.